# Google AMP: amp-list vs php loop - SEO / Pagespeed

Tags: php, json, web, amp-html, amp-list

My AMP page serves a list of reviews.  Each review is an amp-accordion in order to implement nice read-more features.

I am currently in debate whether or not to load the reviews straight into the DOM (php loop) or load them through a JSON file (amp-list).

When I compare the two versions of this page, amp-list wins big in DOMContentLoaded and Load, but they are tied in Finish with a small favor towards the php loop version.

Assuming the php loop version would be completely AMP-Cached, and amp-list would have to poll the stack for the data, which version would be better for overall user experience / seo ?

Thank you!
:D

Answer (score 3):

I think it bases on your purposes. Currently google bot cannot crawl the data which lazyloading so I think amp-list not good for SEO. But Its good for loading time when user or bots landing which also help for SEO. My solution is just load only best stuffs for google bot seeing first which minimum version as possible. Later then when page loaded you can replace with fully version.